# Service setgui running as nobody

Tags: services

I am having a weird issue with one of my services that I’ve setup to run as an AD user and user group using parameters in the conf file, setuid and setgui.
When I run the service with setuid only everything works fine. The moment I add setguid, I get an error in journal saying that setguid operation is not permitted.  After checking the secure file, I can tell that the service is trying to run the setguid as nobody… is this because my default user group differs from my setguid? Any tips?

This is happening in rhel 8.

Comment: Welcome to StackExchange! When you say "parameters in the conf file", do you mean a systemd `*.service` file or some other configuration file? Please clarify by *editing your question post.*

Comment: What is `setgui` or `setguid`? Did you mean `setgid`? Do you use systemd? Do you mean setuid/setgid bits in filesystem? It's rather confusing.

Comment: Apologies, setgid, meaning set group id… a typo on my end

Comment: I mean the .conf file, the main conf file used to fork the binary.

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the problem. My problem was the primary group of the account is not set to what I want to. Every time i start the service by defining setuid and setgid I get an operation not permitted error group because my account It’s defaulting to a different primary group and every time I start the service with the group ID that I want it cause a security violation because im not part of sudoers and cannot change the group. This is not the same thing as changing the ownership of the files i own.